# PHP/MySQL looping through to get totals

Tags: php, mysql

I have three db tables: species, locations, records.

I have nested "while" statements that first loop through the locations to provide table headers. Further nesting accomplishes going through the records page to pull out each record and provide a total count of each species at each location.

I need to add an additional row underneath the last species to provide a count that totals each location.

This cannot be hard-coded since the number of species and locations can vary. Code is already setup to expand the table in both rows and columns. All I need to figure out is how to do the simple calculation of each location's (column) total.

[image: table]

I was thinking I need to do this in some type of an array to load it but I cannot find any real documentation on how I want to do this (at least that I can understand).

Comment: If you provide your table schemas, likely someone will be able to show & explain how to get the info in one query, or with minimal looping/repetition.

Comment: Showing your actual query(s) would be of use. The exact relationship between your 3 tables isn't clear.

Comment: .... and the words to google for are 'pivot table' and/or 'cross tabulation', possibly `WITH ROLLUP` for easy totals.

Comment: species: id (int, AI), name (txt)
locations: id(int, AI), name (txt)
records: id(int, AI), species (int->species id), operation (0=subtract 1=add), quantity (int)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a UNION on this table.
you can create a temporary table first to do this then make a select from it.

roughly:

```
your select.....
UNION
select 'Total',sum(location1),sum(location2),sum(location3) from
(your select) as b
```

Answer (score 0):

Total granny way to do it, but you said you needed something you understand, and I'll bet joins and unions are a little out of your scope. This may not be syntactically correct, but it should get you closer.

---

Removed MySQL | No longer applicable

---

or you can do it in php:

```
<?php
$Results = mysql_fetch_assoc("Select * FROM table");
$locArr = new Array();
foreach($R in $Results){
   foreach($prop in $R){
    $locArr[$prop] += $R[$prop];
   }
}
foreach($prop in $locArr){
   echo $prop."Total: ".$locArr[$prop]."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your idea makes sense but there can be more locations than three. The number of locations is pulled from the locations table.